# Struts 1 action not getting called within javascript function in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts, action, displaytag

I am using the display tag to display my list onto a table. I am trying to have a button to delete a row based on the row id. The id  is getting passed to my javascript function but the action is not getting called. I know the value is getting passed because when I tested using alert to output the id within the function, it did.

I ran firebug and it is saying that my form is undefined

What I have now is

display tag table:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="mainForm" name="MyFormBean">

<display:table requestURIcontext="true" requestURI="/unavailability/loadUnavailability.action?method=loadForm" uid="myList" name="requestScope.unavailList" class="simple" pagesize="10" defaultsort="2" sort="list" cellspacing="0" excludedParams="*">    

<display:column  property="startDate" title="Start Date" width="18%" decorator="com.mhngs.util.DisplayTagDateWrapper" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"/>
<display:column  property="endDate" title="End Date" width="18%" decorator="com.mhngs.util.DisplayTagDateWrapper" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
<display:column  property="reason" title="Comments" width="30%" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />   

<display:column media="html" width="10%">
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:deleteEntry('<c:out value="${myList.rowId}"/>')">Delete</a>
</display:column>


</display:table> 
<input type="hidden" name="rowId" id="rowId" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
    function deleteEntry(rowId){
        document.getElementById('rowId').value=rowId;
        document.forms[0].action='/app/protected/mflc/unavailability/delCounselorEntry.action?method=deleteCounselorUnavailability';
        document.forms['myForm'].submit; //Correction       
    }
```

Struts Form Bean:

```
<form-bean name="MyFormBean" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
<form-property name="myList" type="java.util.List"/>
</form-bean>
```

Struts Delete Mapping:

```
<action path="/unavailability/delCounselorEntry"
        type="com.action.MyAction" 
        scope="request"
        parameter="method" 
        name="MyFormBean">
        <forward name="Success"
            path="/unavailability/myDeleteComfirmationPage.actioncontent" />
    </action>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Anything in the JS console? Is a request being made? If so, what's going out on the wire?

Comment: The JS Console is saying my forms are undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the form was undefined

I had this at first which points to the first form:

```
document.forms[0];              //First <form> element
```

but if you have a name to your form, you need to point to your form like this:

```
document.forms['myForm']; //Points to <form name="name_of_form">
```